# Flag rows that are duplicates in two columns

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, data-validation

My question is similar to [this one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19927/forcing-uniqueness-in-a-google-spreadsheets-column), but adds a little more complexity.

How can I flag duplicate entries in a Google Sheets column unless the duplicates have different values in another column? For instance, consider the table

```
col A    col B
--------------
abc      123
def      123
ghi      456
ghi      456
```

How can I flag the last two rows which are the same in both `col A` and `col B` but not the first two which differ in `col A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **this custom formula is able to flag 1st (cell) occurrence of a duplicate pair:**

```
=COUNTIFS($A1:$A, "="&A1, 
          $B1:$B, "="&B1)<2
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

- **this custom formula is able to flag and protect all duplicate pairs:**

```
=IF(LEN(A1:A), NOT(COUNTIF(
 ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$1:$B), , ROWS($A$1:$A))))),
 ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A1:$B), , ROWS($A1:$A))))))>1), )
```

[image: 1]