# Problem with COUNTIF in Google Sheets Data Validation Custom Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-custom-function, data-validation, google-sheets-data-validation

I am following some [tutorials](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-not-to-allow-duplicates-in-google-sheets/) and [discussion](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19927/forcing-uniqueness-in-a-google-spreadsheets-column) on forcing uniqueness in Google Sheet Column (I need it for ID indexing). I have been using Data Validation for some time, but i have a problem with custom formula and using some functions. I know that that i should use

```
=COUNTIF($A:$A,"="&A1)  < 2
```

or

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:G, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),)))=1
```

But if I enter it to custom formula input box I am pressing "save" button and nothing is happening. It seems like google is stopping me from entering this formula. For other formulas I can save the validation and it is working. Problem is that I don't get any feedback(error) from Google, what is wrong in my formula.

Answer (score 1):

Try to input this formula instead of yours. Maybe is just your locale settings that prevents you from using the formula. Try semicolon instead of comma:

```
=COUNTIF($A:$A; A1)<2
```