# How to force uniqueness of cell in Google Spreadsheet with non-Latin text in cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I have Kannada text in my column and it's not working, but it worked fine with Latin text before. Kannada text is from a region near India. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12ky999IhILN4dEJyRClZ2R0beCASSEY3s9B0BGC1ACI/edit?usp=sharing) is my spreadsheet, there are too many rows to include in this post.

```
word    frequency   
ಮತ್ತು   71520   
ಈ   40233   
ಒಂದು    25255   
ಎಂದು    17046   
ಇದು 15032   
ಅಥವಾ    14527   
ಹಾಗೂ    13709   
ಅವರು    12979   
ಎಂಬ 10660   
ಮೇಲೆ    10581   
ಅವರ 10204   
ಆದರೆ    9271    
ತನ್ನ    9090    
ತಮ್ಮ    8768    
ನಂತರ    8672    
ಮೂಲಕ    7645
```

The validation rule is:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A,"="&A1) < 2
```

That is, on the second row onward, validate that no two cells have the same value. I double checked that the cell that has the red flag on it *doesn't* have a duplicate, and it doesn't, so something must be off with the way unicode values are calculated in that expression or something, any ideas?

I learned how to do this in the first place from [Forcing uniqueness in a Google Spreadsheets column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19927/forcing-uniqueness-in-a-google-spreadsheets-column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple string comparison is case-insensitive, and will also consider certain Unicode glyphs the same even when they look different. For example, the `=` operator will consider the double-wide character `ｅ` (code 65349) the same as the normal Latin `e` (code 101):

- `="ｅ" = "e"` gives `true`
- `=exact("ｅ", "e")` gives `false`

The `countif()` function uses simple comparison operators such as `=`, and thus considers these values the same, among others:

- `ಮೂಲಕ` row 17, `ಮ‌ೂಲಕ` row 3702
- `ನ` row 26, ‌`ನ` row 6581

To compare strings more strictly, use `exact()`, like this:

```
=rows(filter(A$2:A, exact(A$2:A, A2))) < 2
```

You can apply that as a data validation rule to the range `A2:A`, but performance will be abysmal with larger datasets.

Comment: Oh wow it took about 3 minutes after saving that data validation like that for the spreadsheet to update. Slow like you're saying. Is there a better way, would I need custom JavaScript? Actually yeah it crawls when updating, it takes over a minute to update, not real-time like I was expecting.

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to _accomplish_. Your exact requirements remain unclear. If this is a data-entry system, you may be better off by validating each entry just once — at the time it is entered. You do not need to check it again and again after that. Ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.